# git: File shows up as modified immediately after checkout from repo

Tags: git, git-checkout

```
jen.test@wswp0 MINGW64 /c/inetpub/wwwroot/2.0 (master)

$ git fetch


jen.test@wswp0 MINGW64 /c/inetpub/wwwroot/2.0 (master)

$ git checkout origin/master -- testFile.php


jen.test@wswp0 MINGW64 /c/inetpub/wwwroot/2.0 (master)

$ git status testFile.php

On branch master

Changes to be committed:

  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   testFile.php


jen.test@wswp0 MINGW64 /c/inetpub/wwwroot/2.0 (master)

$
```

This is what I was trying to do - I have made changes to several files including testFile.php from another computer. Those files are committed to the repo, and I executed a "git push origin master". I like to get the latest testFile.php from the repo, but not the other files.

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong - try `$ git checkout -- testFile.php`. The changes you made in this file are not reverted using `origin/master`.

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what you think you were trying to do with that `git checkout` command.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be some potential confusion here about what the commands you executed are doing.  When you did `git fetch`, you did update the tracking branch `origin/master`.  But, you *didn't* actually update your local `master` branch, because you never merged or did a `git pull`.  The command:

```
git checkout origin/master -- testFile.php
```

Actually updates your local working copy of `testFile.php` with a version from a different branch.  It might seem confusing, but at the time you did this, your local `master` and the branch `origin/master` were not the same thing.

Then, `git status` reported that this file had been changed versus the HEAD of your local `master` branch.